# Can't import Webkit from gi.repository

Tags: python, webkit, importerror, pygobject, gtk3

When I try to import `Webkit` from `gi.repository`, it gives an `ImportError`:

```
from gi.repository import Webkit
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Webkit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Webkit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your error seems a typo and the library is not found for that.

You have to put "WebKit" instead of "Webkit".

Additionaly if you use Ubuntu check the library existence with:

```
$ locate girepository | grep WebKit
/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/WebKit-3.0.typelib
```

If doesn't exist you need install the package gir1.2-webkit-3.0:

```
# apt-get install gir1.2-webkit-3.0
```

Then on python script:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('WebKit', '3.0')
from gi.repository import WebKit
```

**Note**: For Ubuntu 17.10 or later, the library seems called WebKit2. Which could be installed:

```
$sudo apt-get install gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
```

And found in:

```
$ locate girepository | grep WebKit
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/WebKit2-4.0.typelib
```

You can use in Python like:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import WebKit2
```

Comment: It seems on Ubuntu 17.10 and later it should be gir1.2-webkit2-4.0, so `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-webkit2-4.0` should work...  though unfortunately you can't import Webkit even with it installed.

Comment: Actually you can, but only using gi repository `WebKit2` module which is quite different from the version we had before.

Comment: Thanks I add as note in the reply too, this was a change in more than 6 years ;)